# How to remount /system rw on rooted tablet

Tags: android, firmware

I am trying to remount my system partition. I can change any file in system.img and boot.img. But I can't get partitions mounted as rw! I am rooted.

```
#adb remount
remount succeeded
```

but nothing changes

the same with

```
su; mount -o rw,remount...
```

I set:
`ro.secure=0` in default.prop

`mount cramfs mtd@system /system rw` in  init.rc

But nothing changes! It is still mounted as ro! What have I do to have /system mounted rw?

Comment: mount -o rw,remount,rw /system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mounted **rw**, as `mount` tells you, but **cramfs** stands for **compressed ROM file system**, a filesystem that is intentionally read-only to simplify its implementation, so even if it's mounted **rw** you cannot change it.

Comment: Then, shouldn't it be abbreviated as c**rom**fs?